# pip is able to search package but install fails with error

Tags: python, apache, pip, pypiserver

I have local pypi server, where I uploaded `cffi` package.

When I try to search, it return the package.

```
$ pip search -i https://localhost --trusted-host localhost cffi
cffi (1.11.4)  - 1.11.4
```

But when try to install, it gives error.

```
$ pip install -i https://localhost  --trusted-host localhost cffi==1.11.4
Collecting cffi==1.11.4
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cffi==1.11.4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cffi==1.11.4
```

I am running `pypi` server under `apache` webserver to handle `https` requests on `centos`.

I check the apache log `/var/log/httpd/ssl_access_log`, for `install` command. Its return `200` for `GET Call`.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2018:16:46:23 +0000] "GET /cffi/ HTTP/1.1" 303 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2018:16:46:23 +0000] "GET /simple/cffi/ HTTP/1.1" 200 339
```

I check the log again. For `celery` it works, after that for `cffi` it fails.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2018:16:50:58 +0000] "GET /celery/ HTTP/1.1" 303 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2018:16:50:58 +0000] "GET /simple/celery/ HTTP/1.1" 200 321
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2018:16:50:58 +0000] "GET /packages/celery-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl HTTP/1.1" 200 396437
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2018:16:50:59 +0000] "GET /cffi/ HTTP/1.1" 303 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2018:16:50:59 +0000] "GET /simple/cffi/ HTTP/1.1" 200 339
```

The problem is, for `cffi` its not redirect to `/packages/cffi-1.11.4-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`. While in `celery` its goes to `/packages/celery*` after `GET /simple/celery/`.

I tried to `curl`, to check if there is change in response between these 2 packages, but there is not difference.

```
$ curl -k https://localhost/simple/celery/ -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 25 Jan 2018 16:59:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Content-Length: 321
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Links for celery</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Links for celery</h1>
                 <a href="/packages/celery-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=3ff97b53107b491baeb42f662be14a06">celery-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl</a><br>
        </body>
    </html>
$ curl -k https://localhost/simple/cffi/ -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 25 Jan 2018 16:59:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Content-Length: 339
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Links for cffi</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Links for cffi</h1>
                 <a href="/packages/cffi-1.11.4-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=c9478cf605b4eb2755fa322cc2bf3ddf">cffi-1.11.4-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl</a><br>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two most common problems when facing this issue are either platform mismatch or python version mismatch.

#### python version check

Check what python version your default `pip` refers to - is it the `python3.5`'s `pip`?

```
$ pip -V | grep -o "(.*)"
```

will give you the info. If default `pip` refers to some other python version, invoke the `python3.5`'s `pip` directly with `pip3.5`:

```
$ pip3.5 install -i https://localhost  --trusted-host localhost cffi==1.11.4
```

#### platform check

Try explicitly downloading the `cffi` package for the `manylinux1_x86_64` platform - will the wheel download?

```
$ pip download cffi --only-binary=:all: --platform manylinux1_x86_64 -i https://localhost --trusted-host localhost
```

If the download succeeds, you have a platform mismatch on your target machine. Check what platform is recognized by `pip`:

```
$ python3.5 -c "import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_platform())"
```

#### ABI check

A less common problem is the ABI mismatch: you can check your platform's ABI with

```
$ python3.5 -c "import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_abi_tag())"
```

This string should match the prefix in the wheel name that comes before the platform tag, so in your case, your ABI should be `cp35m`.

---

If you get the `macosx_10_13_x86_64` platform tag, this means you have MacOS High Sierra. On your local PyPI server, you have uploaded the `cffi` wheel that can be installed on linux only (`manylinux` wheel). You won't be able to install it on MacOS High Sierra.  The thing is, `cffi` package ships code partly written in C and compiled for the target platform only. You have three possibilities to solve this:

1. The simplest solution: download the [`macosx_10_13_x86_64` wheel from PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/packages/4e/33/a52ea24466da315c8e545803c9dca55e466e2d53bb6fc1090ba86630af45/cffi-1.11.4-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl#md5=626fb08924bd6a58b892366647837835) and upload it to your local server alongside the `manylinux1` wheel. Now the linux client will get the wheel compiled for linux and you will get the wheel compiled for MacOS when running `pip install cffi`.
2. The "DIY" solution: download the [source tar installer from PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/packages/10/f7/3b302ff34045f25065091d40e074479d6893882faef135c96f181a57ed06/cffi-1.11.4.tar.gz#md5=8ef0f852498908b20bc508799901fe93) and upload it to your local server alongside the `manylinux1` wheel. Now the linux client will get the compiled wheel and MacOS and Windows clients will get the source tar, where they are forced to compile the contained C code locally - if the OS does not provide the right tools, the installation will fail.
3. Configure the local server to proxy the PyPI: if a package is requested, but not found on your local server, it passes the request through to the `pypi.python.org` and if the package is found in the public repository, it is downloaded and passed through your local server as if was found there. Not sure, however, if your server supports this feature. We use `devpi` where it is enough to tell your index that it should have `root/pypi` among its bases: `devpi index -m user/index bases=root/pypi`.

Note that these solutions are not mutually excluding: you can combine 1 with 2 (linux clients will get `manylinux1` wheels, High Sierra gets `macos_10_13` wheel, the rest get the source tar) and even 1, 2 and 3 alltogether. It all depends on what you want/need/can to upload and maintain on your local server.

Comment: hoefling, when I run `pip download cffi` it download the `cffi-1.11.4-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`, and `get_patform` return `macosx_10_13_x86_64`, how to fix this ?

Comment: @Nilesh you have three possibilities, let me write them down in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it helps, I never thought for `whl` as platform specific :)

Comment: @Nilesh It isn't in general, if the package contains only Python code (then you have `None` in the wheel file name, it indicates that the platform is irrelevant), but as soon as there are C extensions, things get pretty hairy pretty fast.

Comment: `pep425tags` is no longer accessible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248524/module-pip-has-no-attribute-pep425tags