# Pypi and Cython

Tags: python, installation, cython, pypi

I'm trying to put together my first PyPi package and am growing confused about some basic aspects of it.

My package depends on `SNPknock`.  When I try to install it on a fresh system (Ubuntu 18.04), I get:

```
pip install snpknock
Collecting snpknock
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/a0/ceb6adc2b7f1a3009f2077c157a99640094021a66f881cb678ecf4
78887f/SNPknock-0.5.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    You don't seem to have Cython installed. Please get a
    copy from www.cython.org and install it
```

I've extracted the `setup.py` [from the tarball here](https://pastebin.com/dyvuM9QR), which includes that error message.

Here is my confusion.  The `setup.py` file specifies Cython as a dependency:

```
DEPENDENCIES = ['Cython>='+CYTHON_MIN_VERSION,
                'numpy>='+NUMPY_MIN_VERSION]
```

However, it also imports Cython, but it seems that it needs to do that in order to cythonize some modules.  It all seems a little circular, but I suspect that either I (or the author of this package) are missing something about this process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be there are no wheels/eggs for you platform. In that case `pip` downloads sources and runs `python setup.py install`. If `setup.py` imports `Cython` it doesn't matter if said `Cython` is listed as a dependency. You must have `Cython` before running `pip install` because `pip` cannot get a list of dependencies from source code without running `setup.py` and `setup.py` requires `Cython` to be importable.

If `snpknock` were ever release an egg or a wheel for your Python version `pip` would download it, get a list of dependencies and install them without consulting `setup.py`; after that it'd install the package. In that case `pip` would automatically download `Cython` or install compiled extensions right from the egg/wheel.

Comment: Thank you!  That's extremely clarifying.  I'm still confused, though: if I look here: https://pypi.org/project/SNPknock/#files I can see an egg file for Python 2.7 on Linux x86_64, which describes the system I was using.  Why would `pip install` grab the `.tar.gz` instead of the `.egg` file?

Comment: Let's try this: `python -c "from pip import pep425tags;print(pep425tags.supported_tags)"` or [other variants](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50248524/7976758) to see the list of supported pep425tags an verify if `[cp27, linux, x86_64]` is there.

Comment: I would think the first tuple below ought to apply, but no? Output: `[('cp27', 'cp27mu', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('cp27', 'cp27mu', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp27', 'none', 'manylinux1_x86_64')
, ('cp27', 'none', 'linux_x86_64'), ('py2', 'none', 'manylinux1_x86_64'), ('py2', 'none', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp27',
 'none', 'any'), ('cp2', 'none', 'any'), ('py27', 'none', 'any'), ('py2', 'none', 'any'), ('py26', 'none', 'any'), 
('py25', 'none', 'any'), ('py24', 'none', 'any'), ('py23', 'none', 'any'), ('py22', 'none', 'any'), ('py21', 'none'
, 'any'), ('py20', 'none', 'any')]`

Comment: No, these tags are concatenated literally. See [Cheetah3](https://pypi.org/project/Cheetah3/#files) as an example. I suspect snpknock's files have been renamed manually so none of the tags apply.

Comment: Linux eggs do not work across distributions. Pip will therefore not use them. What is needed are cross-distribution `manylinux` wheels, which is the replacement for eggs for this very purpose.