# How do I find out which CPython version I am using?

Tags: python, windows, pip, cpython

I am trying to install OpenCV from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv).

I downloaded the following file : **opencv_python‑3.4.3‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl**, 
and when I did `pip install "opencv_python‑3.4.3‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl"`, an error message popped.

**The error** : `opencv_python-3.4.3+contrib-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

From what I understood after some googling and SO-ing, this is an issue due to a **mismatch between the CPython** builds - between the downloaded wheel file and the Python environment on my system.

Therefore, I tried finding ways to determine which CPython version is on my system, but failed.

**What I tried so far:**

```
import platform
platform.python.implementation()
```

Which gave:

```
'CPython'
```

Further, I tried, 
platform.architecture()
which gave:

```
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

I later just scoured through my *site-packages* folder and found somefiles such as `__init__.cpython-36.pyc`, **hence assuming that I am using CPython 3.6**.

**Is there a more programming based method to check the same through the terminal?**

Any kind of help is appreciated. TIA.

Comment: have you try `python -V` or running python in command prompt?

Comment: @cryptonome : No great help there - On doing what you said I got a not-very-concise result.

Comment: `platform.python_version()`

Comment: If you have Python 3.7 installed, run `pip -V` and check what python version is printed. On your machine, `pip` may be an alias to `pip3.6` and not `pip3.7`; if that's true, you need to either adjust your `%PATH%` so the correct binaries come first. Or use `py -3.7 -m pip install` to explicitly select the correct one.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Your trick worked. Thank you. Please put it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @hoefling Thank you very much for the more technical outlook.

Comment: "_a not-very-concise result_" which is? i never run python in windows, but i think it safe to say IDLE on windows would also still have the version printed. hell, even if IDLE doesn't have it printed you can just `import sys; sys.version`

Comment: @cryptonome The result is too large to put it in a comment. I got the help I needed, thank you for trying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `platform` module will provide the python version using:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.python_version()
'3.6.6'
```

Although that said simply running `python` from the command line should provide a header which gives you this information as well.

```
$ python
Python 3.6.6 (default, Sep 12 2018, 18:26:19) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

The `sys` module can weigh in here as well, as it has both `version` and `api_version` routines.

```
>>> sys.version
'3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) \n[GCC 9.4.0]'
>>> sys.api_version
1013
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>>
```

> sys.version
> A string containing the version number of the Python interpreter plus additional information on the build number and compiler used. This string is displayed when the interactive interpreter is started. Do not extract version information out of it, rather, use version_info and the functions provided by the platform module.

> sys.api_version
> The C API version for this interpreter. Programmers may find this useful when debugging version conflicts between Python and extension modules.

Comment: This does not show the cpython version.

Comment: The other answer by quantotto unfortunately does not work, but would give the correct output (ie. `cp37m` vs. `cp37`)

Comment: @DreamFlasher What it does `not` show is the ABI (Application Binary Interface) reference that you appear to want, which will be in the name of the python wheel you installed. What it does show is the python version.

Answer (score 2):

It might also be related to specific ABI tag of your python. Maybe yours is not `cp37m`, where 'm' stands for compilation with pymalloc.

To get your ABI tag, you can `pip install wheel` and then get it programmatically:

```
>>> from wheel.pep425tags import get_abi_tag
>>> get_abi_tag()
'cp37m'
```

Comment: Fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wheel.pep425tags'`

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `pep425tags.py` was replaced with `vendored/packaging/tags.py` in wheel 0.37, yet no alternative functions of `get_abi_tag()` was provided.

Simply add old `pep425tags.py` to root directory of wheel 0.37, and the answer by quantotto works for me.

You can see the replacement details in pull request [#346](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/pull/346).

Answer (score 1):

I needed to get this information in a script to determine which wheel to install from a local filesystem and ended up going with this (it does require having `wheel` installed):

```
python -c 'from wheel.vendored.packaging import tags; print(f"{tags.interpreter_name()}{tags.interpreter_version()}", end="")'
```

Which outputs: `cp38` on my system.

Comment: `pip install wheel` before for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

To print the version and the list of compatible tags:

```
$ path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip debug --verbose
pip version: pip 23.3.1 from /<user home>/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
sys.version: 3.8.15 (default, Nov 24 2022, 04:20:39) 
[GCC 12.2.0]
...
Compatible tags: 429
  cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_36_armv7l
  cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_35_armv7l
  ...
  py30-none-any
```

Thanks to @sinoroc for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60651842/497648).