# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.1.0 (from torchvision==0.3.0)

Tags: python-3.x, pip, torchvision

I am trying to install torchvision and I am using the wheel file to do it, since every time I run `pip install torchvision` I get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'`

I downloaded the following file:
`torchvision-0.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

I got the following error when I tried to install this file:

`ERROR: torchvision-0.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

One of the answers on stackoverflow pointed out to rename the file to win32.whl, and so I did that as well:
`torchvision-0.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl`

On running install on this file I get the following error:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch>=1.1.0 (from torchvision==0.3.0) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch>=1.1.0 (from torchvision==0.3.0)`

Comment: have a look at this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56833162/2139007
make sure your pythondistri/os supports the version you need

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to conquer this problem.

You can either use `pip` (which didn't work in your case).

```
pip install torchvision
```

Another way:

```
conda install torchvision -c pytorch
```

If you want to install a specific version (include the version info):

```
conda install torchvision=0.3.0 -c pytorch
```

Another way, is download the files directly from [`pypi`](https://pypi.org/project/torchvision/#files) or something like [this](https://pypi.org/simple/).

After downloading the correct distribution, you can do:

```
pip install torchvision.whl
```

Another way is to install it through [source](https://github.com/pytorch/vision):

```
python setup.py install
```

Now in your case, to workaround the issue, use `pipenv`. Check [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/10443) post and the answer by @adamshamsudeen.

> pipenv install torch==0.4.1

Notice: The current `torchvision` version is `0.3.0`