# How to fix ImportError: no module named pep425tags

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have been trying to install a python package called PsrPopPy (https://github.com/samb8s/PsrPopPy) in Ubuntu 20.04 but apparently a certain module is missing from the package. See below:

```
juliejt@tulasi:~$ cd PsrPopPy
juliejt@tulasi:~/PsrPopPy$ python setup.py install
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
ImportError: No module named pep425tags:
  File "/home/juliejt/PsrPopPy/SConstruct", line 19:
    import wheel.pep425tags
juliejt@tulasi:~/PsrPopPy$ pip install pep425tags
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pep425tags (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pep425tags
juliejt@tulasi:~/PsrPopPy$ pip install wheel.pep425tags
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel.pep425tags (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel.pep425tags
```

I am not sure how to install the missing wheel.pep425tags file or if there is another way to resolve the issue.

Comment: I am not familiar with the topic but it might be a good idea to check this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248524/module-pip-has-no-attribute-pep425tags

Comment: I don't believe the module still exists. That is what this answer leads one to infer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248524/module-pip-has-no-attribute-pep425tags It's a very old question with very old answers.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I had already checked that question but none of the suggestions there worked. I am inclined to believe the module no longer exists as BoarGules suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, within the SConstruct script you can switch:

```py
import wheel.pep425tags
full_tag = '-'.join(next(tag for tag in wheel.pep425tags.get_supported() if not 'manylinux' in tag))
```

to

```py
import enscons
full_tag = enscons.get_binary_tag()
```

(see, e.g., [this file](https://github.com/dholth/cryptacular/blob/master/SConstruct#L13)).